# Is there any way to configure isearch-forward-regexp invert backslashes usage?

Tags: elisp, regular-expressions, syntax, isearch

It may be handy to make it shortly, for example use `(GET|POST): *\{` instead of `\(GET\|POST\): *{`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just adapt `isearch-search-fun-function`:

```
(defun isearch-extended-regexp-forward ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((regexp-chars "[|{}()`=<>]")
        (isearch-message-prefix-add "Extended ")
        (isearch-search-fun-function
         (lambda ()
           (lambda (regexp &rest other-args)
             (apply (isearch-search-fun-default)
               (replace-regexp-in-string
                regexp-chars "\\\\\\&" regexp t)
               other-args)))))
    (isearch-forward t)))
```

Comment: Excellent! Exactly what I need, thank you!

Comment: Nice workaround!

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid that the answer is no - there is no easy, out-of-the-box way to do that.

This has been discussed in the Emacs Dev mailing list a few times now, as a possible extension to Emacs Lisp.  Well, not just for Isearch but for regexps in general.

Here are two interesting threads about it: [***1***](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2014-09/msg00360.html) and [***2***](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2015-01/msg00724.html).